# How can I search for 00'00"000 using a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, string, time, expression

So I have a number substring that appears twice in my program that looks like this 00'00"000.

I was originally using the regular expression:

```
\d{2}\'\d{2}\"\d{3}
```

and it was working for a few days but now for some reason, it's not? Python's re library isn't finding these substrings at all anymore. What am I doing wrong here?

Code In question:

````
    elif message.content.startswith('%timegap'):
    if message.content == '%timegap -h':
        await client.send_message(message.channel,
                                  '```' + 'Usage: %timegap [time 1] [time 2]\n' + \
                                  """Example: %timegap 03'29"110 03'28"390""" + '```')
    else:
        time_list = re.findall("\d*\'\d+\"\d+", message.content)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, calculate_time_gap(time_list))
````

Comment: Maybe because the input does not contain matching substrings. Check for curly apostrophes/double quotes.

Comment: can you give us an example of the text you're trying to get macthes from?

Comment: Regex is fine, so the problem either lies on the input strings or on your code, which both are missing from the question.

Comment: An example of the text it's searching from: %timegap 03’14”800 03’14”800

Comment: I'm making a discord bot so it's getting the message content from a command I made

Comment: Those are different quotes. They aren't `'` and `"`, they are `’` and `”`.

Comment: Added code to the original post.

Comment: Okay, I was unaware that different types of quotes existed at all. My mind is blown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes from your strings are not the same as the ones in your regex:

```
re.findall(r'\d{2}\’\d{2}\”\d{3}', '%timegap 03’14”800 03’14”800')
> ['03’14”800', '03’14”800']
```

Comment: I was unaware that there were different quotes. I assume a phone would give a different quote so now I have to check for either or. Thank you so much, I appreciate the help.